# Razor page Menu partial get from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I use `razor page` to develop a website and I'm a newbie. I want load data for Menu partial page but I don't know how. My structure as below
[image]

Can you help me how to do it? Or give me a refer link?
Thanks

Comment: You can try to pass data as a model into the partial view.Her is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal solution for this task is a view component (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/view-components). You create a class that inherits from `ViewComponent` e.g. *MenuViewComponent*, and inject your context or data service into the constructor, and use it in an `InvokeAsync` method to generate a model that it passed to the view. The view is a simple razor file named *default.cshtml* located at `/Pages/Shared/Components/<component name>/`, where `<component name>` in this example is *Menu*.